# Laravel get custom model attribute not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

The exact same thing is working for other models in the application but not this one & I can't figure out why. When i try and access the clientname attribute it is blank.

Model

```
class Domain extends Model {

protected $guarded = [];

public function clients() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}

public function getClientNameAttribute() {
    return Client::where('id', $this->client_id)->value('name');
}

}
```

Blade

```
  <tbody>
            @foreach( $domains as $domain )
            {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('domains.index', $domain->id))) !!}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ route('domains.show', $domain->id) }}">{{ $domain->id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $domain->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $domain->clientname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $domain->expiry_date }}</td>
                <td>  {!! link_to_route('domains.edit', 'Edit', array($domain->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
                    </td>
            </tr>
            {!! Form::close() !!}

            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

*edited to add client/domain schema*

Client

```
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('kashflow_id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('contact');
        $table->string('telephone');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('fax');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('address1');
        $table->string('address2');
        $table->string('address3');
        $table->string('address4');
        $table->string('postcode');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Domain

```
            Schema::create('domains', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('expiry_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I deleted my table and made a new migration and everything is working now strangely, thanks to everyone that tried to help

Answer (score 1):

You should define this accessor like so:

```
public function getClientNameAttribute() 
{
    return ($client = $this->clients) ? $client->name : '';
}
```

And then the second thing is that in Blade you should use it like so:

```
$domain->client_name
```

with snake case.

Obviously there's no point to create `clients` relationship either. It should rather have name `client`.

Comment: @ndev So you should probably edit your question and include database schema for client and domain

Comment: @ndev What happens when you use in Blade `$domain->clients->name` - does it display correct value? Are you sure you have clients assigned for domains?

Comment: Hi, there is 100% a client assigned to the domains, when i check in my DB i can see the client_id field is populated but in the application nothing is shown.  `$domain->clients->name` gives me this error : `Trying to get property of non-object`. What i find strange is the exact same method is working for my other models but not this Domain one...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
public function getClientNameAttribute() {
    return Client::where('id', $this->client_id)->first()->name;
}
```

Comment: thanks but doesnt work, `first()` shouldnt have any different effect here since there is no client with the same id

Comment: But, It looks like your Domain model has many clients. Is that correct?

Comment: correct - there are many clients with Domains but I am searching for client by client Id which is the primary key and so only one result will ever be returned.

Comment: But why not simply use a nested model and use $domain->client->name ?

Answer (score 0):

If your model looks like

```
class Domain extends Model {


    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

    public function getClientNameAttribute()
    {
        $client = $this->client;
        return $client ? $client->name : '';
    }

}
```

The code below must works properly(with no errors)

```
<tbody>
    @foreach( $domains as $domain )
    {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('domains.index', $domain->id))) !!}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ route('domains.show', $domain->id) }}">{{ $domain->id }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $domain->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $domain->client_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $domain->expiry_date }}</td>
        <td>  {!! link_to_route('domains.edit', 'Edit', array($domain->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
            </td>
    </tr>
    {!! Form::close() !!}

    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

If any client associated with domain `$domain->client_name` will return his name and `''` otherwise

Comment: My bad, try `$domain->client_name`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing it the wrong way. The attribute names are accessed in snake case. So, you should use:

```
$domain->client_name
```

Comment: the exact same thing(getting client name) is working with my other models/views? also I have tried with `client_name` and it still does not work

Comment: did that work? there is probably something else in other models that is helping. May be method name in those is `getClientnameAttribute`. Notice `n` of `name` is small here

Comment: no & the method name is exactly the same in the other model too

Comment: can you share the code of controller? I think you are not selecting client_id in the selected columns.

Comment: `public function index() {
        $domains = Domain::all();
        return view('domains.index', compact('domains'));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to add a new comment, but I'm always hoping someone can help.

I ran into this problem, and I solved it by changing the signature of the function, going from a function without parameters to a function with a single parameter that is the data of the column to be formatted.

Pass this function

```
public function getRejectedAttribute()
{
    return $this->rejected ? true : false;
}
```

To this other function

```
public function getRejectedAttribute($nRejected)
{
    return $nRejected ? true : false;
}
```